# Why don't the signals emit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

## The Application

I'm trying to build a python shell for my PyQt5 application using the stdlib [`InteractiveConsole`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#interactive-interpreter-objects) so I can let users script live plots. I'm using a `QTextEdit` to display the stdout from the shell.

## The Problem

When I do for loops in the shell, the application freezes because the `insertPlainText()` to the `QTextEdit` is too fast. So I wrote a buffer that would delay the inserts by a few milliseconds. However, I noticed that as soon as I ran any blocking functions like `time.sleep()` in the for loops, it would freeze. So the prints inside the for loops will only be displayed after the loop is done. This does not happen if the buffer is disabled.

For eg, if i do this in the shell:

```
>>>for i in range(10):
...    time.sleep(1)
...    print(i)
...
```

This will only print after 10 seconds.

### Code

This is the most minimal version I could write according to [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines.

Here is the `main.ui` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>main_window</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="main_window">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="tabShape">
   <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="central_widget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="console_layout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QTextEdit" name="console_log">
        <property name="undoRedoEnabled">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
        <item>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="console_prompt">
          <property name="text">
           <string/>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="console_input">
          <property name="frame">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menu_bar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="status_bar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Here is the`main.py` file:

```
import sys
from code import InteractiveConsole
from io import StringIO
from queue import Queue, Empty

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextOption, QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

__author__ = "daegontaven"
__copyright__ = "daegontaven"
__license__ = "gpl3"


class BaseSignals(QObject):
    """
    Standard set of pyqtSignals.
    """
    signal_str = pyqtSignal(str)
    signal_int = pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_float = pyqtSignal(float)
    signal_list = pyqtSignal(list)
    signal_tuple = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    signal_dict = pyqtSignal(dict)
    signal_object = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)


class DelayedBuffer(QObject):
    """
    A buffer that uses a queue to store strings. It removes the
    first appended string first in a constant interval.
    """
    written = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, output, delay):
        """
        :param output: used to access BaseSignals
        :param delay: delay for emitting
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.output = output

        # Set Delay
        self.delay = delay
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.process)
        self.timer.start(self.delay)

    def write(self, string):
        self.queue.put(string)

    def process(self):
        """
        Try to send the data to the stream
        """
        try:
            data = self.queue.get(block=False)
            self.written.emit(data)
        except Empty:
            pass

    def emit(self, string):
        """
        Force emit of string.
        """
        self.output.signal_str.emit(string)


class ConsoleStream(StringIO):
    """
    Custom StreamIO class that emits a signal on each write.
    """
    def __init__(self, enabled=True, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Starts a delayed buffer to store writes due to UI
        refresh limitations.

        :param enabled: set False to bypass the buffer
        """
        StringIO.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.enabled = enabled
        self.output = BaseSignals()

        # Buffer
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.buffer = DelayedBuffer(self.output, delay=5)
        self.buffer.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.buffer.written.connect(self.get)
        self.thread.start()

    def write(self, string):
        """
        Overrides the parent write method and emits a signal
        meant to be received by interpreters.

        :param string: single write output from stdout
        """
        if self.enabled:
            self.buffer.write(string)
        else:
            self.output.signal_str.emit(string)

    def get(self, string):
        self.output.signal_str.emit(string)


class PythonInterpreter(QObject, InteractiveConsole):
    """
    A reimplementation of the builtin InteractiveConsole to
    work with threads.
    """
    output = pyqtSignal(str)
    push_command = pyqtSignal(str)
    multi_line = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.l = {}
        InteractiveConsole.__init__(self, self.l)
        self.stream = ConsoleStream()
        self.stream.output.signal_str.connect(self.console)
        self.push_command.connect(self.command)

    def write(self, string):
        self.output.emit(string)

    def runcode(self, code):
        """
        Overrides and captures stdout and stdin from
        InteractiveConsole.
        """
        sys.stdout = self.stream
        sys.stderr = self.stream
        sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__
        result = InteractiveConsole.runcode(self, code)
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
        return result

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def command(self, command):
        """
        :param command: line retrieved from console_input on
                        returnPressed
        """
        result = self.push(command)
        self.multi_line.emit(result)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def console(self, string):
        """
        :param string: processed output from a stream
        """
        self.output.emit(string)


class MainWindow:
    """
    The main GUI window. Opens maximized.
    """
    def __init__(self):

        self.ui = uic.loadUi("main.ui")
        self.ui.showMaximized()

        # Console Properties
        self.ui.console_log.document().setMaximumBlockCount(1000)
        self.ui.console_log.setWordWrapMode(QTextOption.WrapAnywhere)

        self.ps1 = '>>>'
        self.ps2 = '...'
        self.ui.console_prompt.setText(self.ps1)

        # Spawn Interpreter
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.thread.start()

        self.interpreter = PythonInterpreter()
        self.interpreter.moveToThread(self.thread)

        # Interpreter Signals
        self.ui.console_input.returnPressed.connect(self.send_console_input)
        self.interpreter.output.connect(self.send_console_log)
        self.interpreter.multi_line.connect(self.prompt)

    def prompt(self, multi_line):
        """
        Sets what prompt to use.
        """
        if multi_line:
            self.ui.console_prompt.setText(self.ps2)
        else:
            self.ui.console_prompt.setText(self.ps1)

    def send_console_input(self):
        """
        Send input grabbed from the QLineEdit prompt to the console.
        """
        command = self.ui.console_input.text()
        self.ui.console_input.clear()
        self.interpreter.push_command.emit(str(command))

    def send_console_log(self, command):
        """
        Set the output from InteractiveConsole in the QTextEdit.
        Auto scroll scrollbar.
        """
        # Checks if scrolled
        old_cursor = self.ui.console_log.textCursor()
        old_scrollbar = self.ui.console_log.verticalScrollBar().value()
        new_scrollbar = self.ui.console_log.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
        if old_scrollbar == new_scrollbar:
            scrolled = True
        else:
            scrolled = False

        # Sets the text
        self.ui.console_log.insertPlainText(command)

        # Scrolls/Moves cursor based on available data
        if old_cursor.hasSelection() or not scrolled:
            self.ui.console_log.setTextCursor(old_cursor)
            self.ui.console_log.verticalScrollBar().setValue(old_scrollbar)
        else:
            self.ui.console_log.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
            self.ui.console_log.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
                self.ui.console_log.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
            )


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The class `BaseSignals` is needed for communication between the main thread and the interpreter. Here is a [transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/145252/2017/5/27) as to why this was implemented.

### What I know

This line is responsible for inserting the plain text `self.output.signal_str.emit(data)`. This `emit()` happens inside a `QThread`. So until the multiple `self.buffer.write()` is finished the `emit()` won't be processed. I thought adding a `QApplication.processEvents()` in `DelayedBuffer.process()` would help. It doesn't. I admit I could however be wrong about this.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As with the other question, this very much **does** warrant an [mcve]. Linking to offsite resources like github is not an acceptable substitute for that.

Comment: @ekhumoro How much more simple can I make this ? The simplest version  is 160 lines without buffering. Trust me, this is as simple as it gets. Unless you want me to put the whole source here. The last time I tried a minimal version for this topic, key ideas were lost. I wouldn't do this if I had no choice.

Comment: If you have an MCVE, please put the full code in the question itself rather than linking to an offsite resource.

Comment: Probably not related but... why is the call `data = self.queue.get(block=False)` non-blocking (I think)?  That will result in that thread being essentially a busy-waiting loop -- which can't be helping things.

Comment: @G.M. I believe it already is a busy thread becuase of the while loop. So it's irrelevant. Keeping the `get()` non-blocking gives finer control on whats happening and makes debugging easier.

Comment: @ekhumoro I've updated with an MVCE. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: @daegontaven. I cannot reproduce the problem. If I disable the delayed buffer, everything works as expected, with no freezing.

Comment: Same here: passing `enabled=False` to the ConsoleStream, everything works as expected (PyQt 5.8.1 on Windows). Even with a `time.sleep(0.01)` in a `for i in range(1000)`. What exactly do you mean when you say it freezes?

Comment: @Jeronimo yeah I know. It will work without the buffer. That is the problem. Set it to True and try. It won't work. It won't freeze but you'll know it when you see it. The output will come out after the loop is done. Everything works like a charm as long as the buffer is disabled.

Comment: @daegontaven. So why use the buffer at all? What problem is it supposed to solve? In your question, you claim that your application freezes without the buffer. But so far, no one else is able to reproduce that.

Comment: @ekhumoro I never said it freezes without the buffer. I said it freezes the with it enabled. I said the performance is bad. Try writing a large loop in the interpreter. It will be unresponsive. Lots of people have reproduced this bug. The bug is not in question. The buffer was made so it would not crash in the case of 10000 of prints from a long loop. But the buffer made things worse by introducing the `time.sleep` bug.  While Linux distros may be able to handle(somewhat.. Not great) the buffer turned off with some grace.. Windows will just plain freeze.

Comment: @daegontaven. Your question says: "the application freezes because the insertPlainText() to the QTextEdit is too fast. So I wrote a buffer that would delay the inserts". It does not mention performance issues, or problems with running long loops. More to the point, your example code doesn't demonstrate any of these things either. If you really want help, help people to help you by giving them all the information they need.

Comment: @daegontaven. I tried the example script using a loop that does 10,000 prints, with no delayed buffer. The performance bottleneck (such as it is) is almost entirely caused by the code in the `send_console_log` method. If I comment out the block that resets the cursor/scrollbar, it only takes a few seconds to print all the lines - and using a `QPlainTextEdit` reduces that to about a second. Beyond that, you are simply running into the limitations of the widget itself. A loop of 50,000 prints takes about five seconds. So no bugs - just inefficient code.

Comment: @ekhumoro While I admit It never occurred to me that the auto scroll was causing some lag, I see absolutely no change on Windows machines. It is still not responding with the buffer turned off. It is not about any particular loop size. It should be able to run any loop like a normal interpreter. Thank you for that observation though.

Comment: @daegontaven. You say it "should be able to run any loop like a normal interpreter", but I don't think that is really true. The fact is, `QTextEdit/QPlainTextEdit` is just not designed to handle a continuous stream of small updates. People have been complaining about this for *years*. But no matter what optimisations have been tried, there is just no getting away from the intrinsic limitations of the widget itself. At some point, most people just give up and either use a different widget (e.g. `QListView`), or write their own custom widget, or try a third-party solution (e.g. qtconsole).

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes all of these issues were actually discussed multiple times on forums and IRC channels. I see now I should have included everything... I mean everything. This is why I needed a buffer originally. I don't set bounties on questions without doing proper research first. I am fine with a decrease in write speed. So I need the buffer to be enabled and to work.

Comment: @daegontaven. By "work", I assume you are mostly referring to windows (although obviously not at the expense of other platforms). I really think your question should state that much more clearly, given how easy it was to "fix" the problem on linux. It would also be good to provide some evidence that a delayed buffer is actually capable of solving the problem. I assume you must have got the idea from elsewhere, and that someone must have successfully implemented something similar in one of their own projects.

Comment: @ekhumoro It was recommended to me by altendky on IRC. When I exhausted all other options. Delay writes by a smal interval so the widgets have some breathing room. I don't think I've seen any other projects use that solution though. I have seen fully functional interpreters like in Spyder IDE or in qtconsole. So I know it is possible. And Its evident becuase the GUI doesn't freeze when the buffer is enabled. Just the time.sleep stops working. Someone on one of the forums said it might be an issue with the object tree and parent not set for the objects. I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: I think you can use `Application.processEvents()` in this loop.

Comment: @ADR Nopes. I don't make bounties without testing every case. I'm very certain that this will not work and has not worked in the 3 months that I've been trying to solve this problem. I am certain that the problem lies in Python and Qt as it has a GIL that is blocking concurrent execution of code. I am indeed frustrated to say there is no solution to this problem. I will edit the question to reflect this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpreter thread is blocking on the `InteractiveConsole.runcode()` call.  It will not be able to process any signals until this call completes.  That is why you see the delayed output.

You can get the effect you're after by changing

```
self.interpreter.output.connect(self.send_console_log)
```

to

```
self.interpreter.stream.output.signal_str.connect(self.send_console_log)
```

For some old school debugging, disconnect you're stderr handling and sprinkle some print statements around like...

```
print('runcode after', file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Amazing, this solved the problem. After some tweaking I was even able to get rid of `BaseSignals` altogether.  Thank you so much.